# Parsing in VBscript

Tags: vbscript, string-parsing

I have a text file dump pasted below that I need to display only the size of the disk(s), for instance in a msgbox.In this case below it will display (500.1GB) 3 times, one for every HDD size. I am not exactly sure how to do it. There is no set spacing that I could delimit. I have pasted the code below. Any help would be greatly appriciated.

```
<DISK LIST>                                      

Disk  State   Disk Type   Port Type      Speed   Size    Free     CA      
---- -------- -------- ---------------- ------- ------- ------- ------- 
0    Online   Disk     SATA-II/NCQ      6Gb/sec 500.1GB 492.0GB  -RW 
1    Online   Disk     SATA-II/NCQ      6GB/sec 500.1GB 492.0GB  -RW
2    Online   Disk     SATA-II/NCQ      6GB/sec 500.1GB 492.0GB  -RW


<ARRAY LIST>
...
```

This is the code that I do have so far.

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Dim match, sizeCount, tempArray, foundSection
match = false
matchString = "Size"
foundSection = false

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\dump.txt", ForReading, True)

Do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
  strLine = objTextFile.ReadLine

  if strLine <> "" then
    tempArray = Split(strLine," ",-1,1)
    match = true
      End If

If InStr(strLine, matchString) = 0 Then
  wscript.echo("found")
    foundSection = true
End If

if (match) then
  If (IsNumeric(tempArray(0))) Then
    sizeCount = sizeCount + 1
      disksize = disksize & Trim(tempArray(0)) & " "  
  End If
End if

If (tempArray(0)) = "<ARRAY" Then
  foundSection = false
End If
Loop
Wscript.Echo("disk size =" & disksize)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. The idea is to use the separator line of dashes to locate character positions which are relevant to Size.

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Dim sizeStart, sizeEnd ' the character position at which Size starts and ends

Main

Sub Main()
    Dim bDisplay, strLine
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\dump.txt", ForReading, True)

    bDisplay = False
    Do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
        strLine = objTextFile.ReadLine
        ' Stop Display once no length line is met
        If Len(strLine) = 0 Then
            bDisplay = False
            sizeStart = 0
            sizeEnd = 0
        End If
        If bDisplay And sizeStart + sizeEnd > 0 Then
            Wscript.Echo "disk size = " & Mid(strLine, sizeStart, sizeEnd - sizeStart)
        End If
        If InStr(1, strLine, "--") > 0 Then
            GetSizeStartEndPositions strLine
            bDisplay = True
        End If
    Loop
    objTextFile.Close
End Sub

Sub GetSizeStartEndPositions(sLine)
    '  |Disk  State   Disk Type   Port Type      Speed   Size    Free     CA
    '  |---- -------- -------- ---------------- ------- ------- ------- -------
    'i |----1--------2--------3----------------4-------5-------6-------7-------
    '  |                                                ^     ^
    ' Size is between 5th and 6th space in the separater line with dashes
    '
    Const SpaceStart = 5
    Const SpaceEnd = 6
    Dim i, pos
    i = 1
    pos = 1
    Do
        pos = InStr(pos, sLine, " ", vbTextCompare) + 1
        If i = SpaceStart Then sizeStart = pos
        If i = SpaceEnd Then sizeEnd = pos - 1
        i = i + 1
    Loop Until pos >= Len(sLine)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your input file seems to have a fixed format with no spaces in the data values I'd probably do something like this:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "\s+"
re.Global  = True

Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\dump.txt")
Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
  line = Trim(f.ReadLine)
  If line = "<DISK LIST>" Then        'process lines following "<DISK LIST>"
    For i=1 To 3 : f.SkipLine : Next  'skip header lines

    Do Until line = "" Or f.AtEndOfStream
      line = Trim(f.ReadLine)
      line = re.Replace(line, " ")    'collapse adjacent spaces to a single one
      arr  = Split(line)              'split line into array
      If UBound(arr) > -1 Then
        WScript.Echo arr(5)           'print 6th field (size)
      End If
    Loop

    Exit For  'no need to read the rest of the file
  End If
Loop
f.Close
```